# How to use Composer dependent software in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php

There are some useful programs written with Composer in mind, meaning the author/s have used some parts of some other program and using Composer it will download these dependencies and make the appropriate configuration, namespacing etc.

I would like to use some of these programs in WordPress in my plugin with using require_once() and including the program(app) so I can use its functions from my WordPress plugin.

How to do that?

Comment: So, it's not possible or the hacking of wordpress would be enormous? Can some heavy-weight Composer and WordPress users elaborate on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to use some of these programs in WordPress in my plugin with using require_once() and including the program(app) so I can use its functions from my WordPress plugin.

Thats possible, but a really bad practice.

- You have a plugin folder with a working wordpress plugin.
- You add `composer.json` and require a third-party package.
- You trigger `composer install` and the third-party package gets fetched into the folder `vendor` inside your `plugin` folder.
- Inside your plugin you include `vendor\autoload.php`, which is the Composer Autoloader. That's the autoloader for all third-party plugins.
- Then you might start to work with third-party classes (without require).

Again, regarding the loading: your plugin is loaded by Wordpress. But your plugin loads its external dependencies itself by including the Composer Autoloader.

When everybody includes Composer packages on the plugin level, then different Wordpress plugins might ship the same Composer packages, right? Ok, lets add 50 different plugins with 10 times the same dependency: crap-ton inside crap-ton.

In other words: including Composer packages directly in plugins works, but is a really bad practice for the Wordpress ecosystem.

---

The correct way to solve this would be to use Composer on the application level (Wordpress) and not on the plugin level. That means that Wordpress has the vendor folder and all plugins might include code from there - instead of multiple plugins possibly having a vendor folder each.

There are a lot of different approaches out there to handle things a bit more centralized. I really don't know what the current state of Composer integration on the Wordpress core is. That answer is better given by a member of the Wordpress team. In other words: ask for community guidance over at the official Wordpress support.

- http://wpackagist.org/
- https://github.com/coenjacobs/wordpress-composer-installer
- Composer/Installers Wordpress

Lets go through the last one: "Composer Installer for Wordpress"

This installer handles `plugin`, `theme` and `muplugin` package types. See https://github.com/composer/installers/blob/master/src/Composer/Installers/WordPressInstaller.php

How does that work? You need to add a `composer.json` to your plugin and add "wordpress-plugin" as "type" and require the "composer installer" as a dependency of the package.

```
{
  "name": "my/plugin",
  "type": "wordpress-plugin",
  "require": {
    "composer/installers": "v1.0.6"
  }
}
```

When you run `composer install`, Composer will fetch the composer/installer and recognize the type "wordpress-plugin". It will then install the plugin into `wp-content/plugins/{$name}/`.

You can also add more packages to the "require" section.